# Create a service like thread in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-activity

I am creating a google maps application in Android. What I want is that even after a user closes my app, I want to create a service, beforehand, that still runs in the background and sends me the current location of the user.

Now when a user exits from 5m radius of a particular location, I want that background thread to stop.

Is that possible? If yes, how can I implement it. A good direction or a web page tutorial or a code snippet will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what have you attempted so far? show us the code

Comment: Nothing yet. I an new at this, and wanted to know if this is even possible. If yes, then a link to some tutorial would be a great help. Or any kind of direction will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question it is possible. Look into the [FusedLocationProviderAPI](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi).

Specifically, you need to look into the method requestLocationUpdates(). There are several different method signatures that allow you to pass in PendingIntents (for Background Location Requests) as well a LocationListener (for Foreground Requests).

Comment: Doesnt FuseLocationProvide requires GooglePlayServices to run? Because before this, I created another module that fetches current location using this tutorial - https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

But it did not work, so I followed another approach of using GPS and network provider, which worked.

Comment: Asking for the last known location has no guarantees. Yes, you have to employ GooglePlayServices, but the background management (power, network) is all handled by this API. LocationManager is very clunky.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? Because GoogleApiClient was not working in my app. Can you please let me know how to employ GooglePlayServices. Do I have to download any jar? or use a library from my android studio? If I use GooglePlayServices, will my client application has to install something before they can use my app?

Comment: Did you install GooglePlayServices from your SDK manager? If the phone is an Android device then it shoudl have GooglePlayService

Comment: No I did not yet install it from SDK manager. I was looking at that right now. Yes my phone is android.

Comment: I have one more question for you. If I use Google Play Services, my clients (people who will download this app) will not have to update or install Google Play services in their phone to use my app. Right?